# Show the list of all product's names ordered along with first and last names of the customers

Tags: mysql, sql, adminer

I was doing an exercise and I am stuck on it. There are 2 tables:

- Customers(id, firstname, lastname, address)
- Orders (id, product_name, product_price, date_order DATE, id_customer, amount)

The query:

```
SELECT Orders.product_name, Customers.firstname, Customers.lastname
FROM Orders INNER JOIN
     Customers
     ON Orders.id_customer=Customers.id
ORDER BY Orders.id;
```

Expected result:

Show the list of all products' names ordered along with first and last names of the customers.

Include in the result only those customers who have no address in a database and sort the data by `Orders.id`.

Comment: i assume this is a homework/job interview related question?  Read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) .. Also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're pretty close. You just need a `WHERE` clause to match this requirement:

> Include to the result only those customers who has no address in a database

Try this:

```
SELECT Orders.product_name, Customers.firstname, Customers.lastname
FROM Orders INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.id_customer = Customers.id
WHERE address IS NULL OR address = ''
ORDER BY Orders.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one more condition of address as null

```
   SELECT Orders.product_name, 
     Customers.firstname, 
    Customers.lastname FROM Orders 
    INNER JOIN Customers ON 
    Orders.id_customer=Customers.id 
    and  Customers.address IS NULL
    ORDER BY Orders.id;
```